# How to get all substrings using a list of keywords

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I am using a script in Google Sheets to search the string in a cell to determine if any of my keywords are in the string. If a keyword is in the string, then I want to append it to the result and then display all keywords found in the string.

This mostly works, but I'm finding that the first keyword of each search string is missed. Any suggestions?

```
function findKeyWordsInString(keywordRange, searchString)
{
  var result = "";

  // Loop through the rows in keywordRange
  for (var row = 0; row < keywordRange.length; row++)
  {
    // Loop through the columns in keywordRange
    for (var col = 0; col < keywordRange[row].length; col++)
    {
      var keyword = keywordRange[row][col];

      if (keyword != null && keyword != "")
      {
        // Found a non-null, non blank value, check if it exists in the searchString
        if (searchString.indexOf(keyword) > 0)
        {
          result = result + keyword + ", ";
        }
      }
    } 
  } 

  if (result == "")
  {
    result = "-";
  }
  else
  {
    result = result.substr(0, result.length - 2);
  }

  return (result);
}
```

My spreadsheet has the keywords in column A and the search strings in column C.

Here is what I'm using to call the function:

```
=findKeyWordsInString(A2:A, C3)
```

C3 contains:

```
Accomplishment, Awareness, Credibility, Seriousness, Attentiveness
```

The correct response should be:

```
Accomplishment, Awareness, Credibility, Attentiveness
```

The actual result is:

```
Attentiveness, Awareness, Credibility
```

`Accomplishment` is missing

Comment: In order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide a sample spreadsheet? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Note that `indexOf` has a minimum value of -1, not 0. And that `null == ""` is true. Review truthy falsy, strict equality, and `indexOf` in your preferred documentation.

Comment: The fix was to change:
if (searchString.indexOf(keyword) > 0)
to 
if (searchString.indexOf(keyword) > -1)

Thanks for the assist tehhowch!